# Is it possible to get a refresh token for Azure Resource Manager API with the client credentials flow?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, refresh-token

I have a long running ADF pipeline that uses a token for management.azure.com to query data from the ADF API. Is it possible to get a refresh token which should have a much longer life than the +-1 hour life of the normal access token? I've seen with other scopes you can use offline_access to get the refresh token but this doesn't seem valid for management.azure.com.
Currently I'm doing a post to [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BTenantId%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token) with the following request body and successfully getting back an access token.

grant_type=client_credentials

client_id=XXXXX

client_secret=XXXXX

scope=https://management.azure.com/.default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note** that: It is not possible to generate refresh token for client credential flow as there is no user interaction involved. Refer this [**blog**](https://medium.com/@shoaib.alam/part-3-oauth-2-0-client-credentials-grant-with-azure-ad-36ac0f9ab2b7) by *Shoaib Alam*.

Instead, you can try to **increase the access token lifetime** by using the below Microsoft Graph API query:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/tokenLifetimePolicies
Content-type: application/json

{
    "definition": [
        "{\"TokenLifetimePolicy\":{\"Version\":1,\"AccessTokenLifetime\":\"23:59:59\"}}"
    ],
    "displayName": "Contoso token lifetime policy",
    "isOrganizationDefault": true
}
```

[image]

**The access token now is valid for 24 hours:**

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
grant_type:client_credentials
scope:https://management.azure.com/.default
```

[image]

- You can also assign the policy to a Microsoft Entra application. Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-tokenlifetimepolicies?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request)
- The access token lifetime policy can be set to minimum 5 minutes to maximum is 1,440 minutes (24 hours).

**References:**

[Set lifetimes for tokens using PowerShell - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/configure-token-lifetimes#create-a-policy-and-assign-it-to-an-app)

[Create tokenLifetimePolicy - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/tokenlifetimepolicy-post-tokenlifetimepolicies?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This makes sense and is the best solution for my situation!

Comment: Great to know:)